# What is the difference between 'askquestion' and 'askyesno' in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkmessagebox

What is the difference between the `askquestion()` and `askyesno()` functions of messagebox in Tkinter?

I found those two functions in this website: http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/tkMessageBox.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/tkinter/messagebox.py):

```
def askquestion(title=None, message=None, **options):
    "Ask a question"
    return _show(title, message, QUESTION, YESNO, **options)

def askyesno(title=None, message=None, **options):
    "Ask a question; return true if the answer is yes"
    s = _show(title, message, QUESTION, YESNO, **options)
    return s == YES
```

Thus, the difference is that `askquestion` will return `YES` or `NO`, meanwhile `askyesno` will return a boolean.

Comment: Cool. Thanks! Now I have a follow up question. Do you know why the authors of tkinter made these two functions when one of the functions seems enough?

Comment: I don't know. They were both [introduced](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/e88b69d52b33ad67f459aec3f45c8436b9bb282f) by Fred Lundh in July 1997, so you probably should search for discussions involving that person in the mailing list archives prior to that date :)